# Syntax error for a simple try-exception-if

Tags: python, if-statement, syntax, try-catch

I get an error when simulating the following simple code in python:

```
try:
    name = input()
    #your code goes here
    
    if len(name) < 4: raise NameError("error")
except:
    print("Invalid Name")
```

The error message is here:

```
if len(name) < 4: raise NameError("error")
^
Syntax error: invalid syntax
```

Best regards,
Thank you

Comment: Cannot reproduce. The posted code works for me.

Comment: You say "when simulating" ... is this the exact code that fails?

Comment: A problem with indentation perhaps?

Comment: I tried the exact code in my visual studio code editor and it's working fine. When the name's length is greater than 4, it shows nothing but when the name is less than 4 it shows me **Invalid Name**. I don't why the problem is occurring from your side.

Comment: maybe check to make sure you don't have a mix of tabs and spaces?

Comment: And also I've literally copied and pasted the code. Same code, same spaces, same comments!

Comment: Thank you guys, I am using solo learn compiler. So this problem may arise from the bugs available in this compiler. I have posted my message somewhere else and they advice to modify indentations. Anyway problem exists yet. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in the comments following the question, some of compilers do not give any error when running the code. But others may give.
In order to solve the problem, you must know that Tab key is different from four space in these compilers. So, the error-free code is here:

```
try:
    name = input()
 
    if len(name)<4:
        raise NameError 
    else:
        print("Account Created")
except:
    print("Invalid Name")
```

To describe more, before "name", if, and else you must put a single tab not four spaces. Also, the statement inside if needs a double Tab to work well.

I hope other guys take advantage of this question-answer. Please like both the question and answer if it was helpful.

Best regards,
Thank you